# How to replace 'innerHTML' of tag that has specific class (the nth occurrence) (using regex)?

Tags: php, regex, string, preg-replace

### What I am trying to achieve

I am trying to replace the 'innerHTML' of any (in my case) html tag, that has a specific class assigned to it, within a `file_get_contents()` string, without altering the other content. Later I will create a file (with `file_put_contents()`).

I am specifically trying to avoid the use of DOMDocuments, Xpath, simple_html_dom because these alter the formatting of a document.

The class markers are just a way to mark the elements in the source, like lightbox does. Marking with a class seemed most elegant, but maybe marking elements in a different way makes the solution easier? I doubt it will make a difference though.

---

The code should also match when:

- when `class="..."` contains other classes
- when innerHTML contains other tags

It is not necessary but it would be amazing if it even matches if:

- There is php in `class="..."`
- php inbetween `class="..."` and `>`

### What I have tried

*(in counter-chronological order)*

**1 -** trying to work with the following fucntion I've found in other so answers and php.net:

```
function preg_replace_nth($pattern, $replacement, $subject, $nth=1) {
    return preg_replace_callback($pattern,
        function($found) use (&$pattern, &$replacement, &$nth) {
                $nth--;
                if ($nth==0) return preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, reset($found) );
                return reset($found);
        },$subject ,$nth  );
}
```

I am not a regex expert and in combination with the php functions it becomes, for me, very difficult, that's why I ask for help. (I've been working on this for an hour or 8.)

I tried feeding it the following regex pattern (did many small alterations:

```
  1  '#(?<=class=\"classToMatch\".*?>).*?(?=</)#';
```

For the last 30 alterations it keeps returning:

> Warning: preg_replace_callback(): Compilation failed: lookbehind assertion is not fixed length at offset xx

Things I realise that are perhaps problematic for regex:

- I do not have the luxury to be able to look for a specific closing tag (e.g. `</h2>`) because the tag could be any element. If really necesarry, maybe I should limit my request to `<p>, <h(x)> and <a>` elements.
- I think dealing with nested elements might become problematic.

---

**2 -** working with simple_html_dom and DOMDocument

First I was delighted to see that it worked, but when I opened the source code of the edited document I was horrified because it deleted a lot of formatting.

This was the working code and should be fine for anyone working with html documents with little php and javascript.

```
$nth = 0;              // nth occurrence (starts with 0)
$replaceWith = '';     // replacement string

$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTMLFile("source.php");

// find all elements with specific class
$finder = new DomXPath($dom);
$nodes = $finder->query("//*[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' classname ')]");

if (!is_int($nodes->length) || $nodes->length < 1) die('No element found');

$nodeToChange = $nodes->item($nth);

$nodeToChange ->removeChild($nodeToChange ->firstChild);
$fragment = $dom->createDocumentFragment();
$fragment->appendXML($replaceWith);
$lentNodeToEdit->appendChild($fragment);

$dom->saveHTMLFile("test.php");
```

---

**3 -** things with strpos etc. and I am currently considering returning to these functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following regex might be helpful to you:

```
<(?<tag>\w*)\sclass=\"lent-editable\">(?<text>.*)</\k<tag>>
```

You will need to find the group name "text", which is the inner HTML you want to replace.

Comment: Wow, that is a step forward already :D Yet it now replaces the whole tag and not just its innerHTML. Also, could you perhaps explain a little bit how it works? Especially how the parts within <> work.

Comment: This regex will match the whole tag, so you don't want to replace the entire match. Instead, you'll want to find the regex capture group named "text", and the value of that group is the inner HTML that you'll want to replace. I don't know how to do this in PHP (I'm a C# guy), but if you do an Internet search for "php regex capture group", you'll be headed in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks! Will do that definitely. Your regex doesn't match tag with multiple classes, how should I adapt it to match class="otherclass classToMatch perhapsmore" and what if the tag has an atribute beween class and the closing '>'(containing multiple classes)

Comment: Thank you. I now understand how (?<tag>) etc. works. I am able to call these in the replacement string. Therefore I am now capturing prefix and suffix: (?<prefix><(?<tag>\w*)\sclass=\"lent-editable\">)(?<text>.*)(?<suffix></\k<tag>>)

Comment: Great! Would you mind marking my response as the answer?

Comment: No I can't. It is not the answer. I'll upvote for helping me.